# SQL INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, view, information-schema

I want to make 2020 that include 2019 for all view contents, but I have a problem with the long views.Is View Definition column has a character limit? Because as far as I can see, there is a problem with views that are too long codes.Is there a remedy?

```
declare @Icerik varchar(max)
declare pcursor cursor
for
SELECT VIEW_DEFINITION FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS WHERE TABLE_NAME like '%2019%'
open pcursor
fetch next from pcursor into @Icerik
    while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        begin
            set @Icerik = replace(@Icerik,'2019','2020')
            exec (@Icerik)
            fetch next from pcursor into @Icerik
        end
    close pcursor
    deallocate pcursor
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is View Definition column has a character limit?

From [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/views-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

> VIEW_DEFINITION   **nvarchar(4000)**  If the length of definition is larger than nvarchar(4000), this column is NULL. Otherwise, this column is the view definition text.

---

I suggest to use [sys.sql_modules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-sql-modules-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

> definition     **nvarchar(max)**   SQL text that defines this module. This value can also be obtained using the OBJECT_DEFINITION built-in function.

**[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8e12ba1fcbd39115b5dfdd02ec6ee586)**

Alternatively `SELECT OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID('schema.view_name'))`

Comment: `sys.views` surely?

Comment: @Charlieface [db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c574a748e460ef9a481b1a048c8e211d) Sys.views does not contain view's definition

Comment: And `sys.sql_modules` doesn't contain the name or whether it is a view, just `object_id`, so either way you need to join `sys.views` or `sys.objects`. You can get the definition with `OBJECT_DEFINTION(object_id)` anyway